# How download dropbox directory or files with command line on a linux server

Tags: linux, dropbox, wget

I need to move a very big directory from dropbox to S3 ~250GB, but don't find an easy way to do it. (I don't have credential of dropbox it is a shared link)

1) From my browser trying to download the folder result in 'error zip to large', however I can dl the files inside this folder 1 by 1 on my workstation but it is going to be a pain plus we share the connexion at work so I wanted to use an amazon temp server to retrieve 1 by 1 the file then send them to S3.

2) Second problem the direct link that dropbox give you are not really direct link they contain the name of folder plus at the end "?dl=0&preview=1GQKV9M.vcf#" 
and copying the link and then past it in another tab doesn't start any new download. As a result trying to use wget or changing dl=0 per dl=1 also result in errors.

Comment: You have to quote special chars, for example with single quotes: `wget 'http://https://www.dropbox.com/s/foo/bar?dl=0'`. Not sure if it needs `dl=0` or `dl=1`. And I don't think the preview part should there - you want to download, not preview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just found a way to direct download :) !

The new link dropbox gives:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxx/test.txt?dl=0
change it to:
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xxxxxxx/test.txt?dl=1

so www becomes: dl
and 0 becomes 1

Comment: Thank you it works perfect for me! it could have saved me a lot of clicking :)