# Dropbox download file from shared link via command line

Tags: command-line, dropbox

I know I can download files from Dropbox with wget by replacing dl=0 to dl=1 (e.g. [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1189060/how-download-dropbox-directory-or-files-with-command-line-on-a-linux-server)).

What I' am wondering is if I have a link to a shared folder on Dropbox can download specific files within a shared folder using wget? Or do I have to create shared links to each individual file?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. While you cannot modify the link, you can use `--accept` option.

```
wget --no-check-certificate -r --level 3 --accept "beach_photo.jpg" "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/...?dl=1"
```

You can use asteriks as a joker value, like `"beach_photo.*"` or `"*.mp4"`